# Nested timeout python

Tags: python, process, timeout, timeoutexception

I would like to call a function with a timeout (TIMEOUT1), where this function calls a different process with itself a timeout (TIMEOUT2). I am not sure how to have nested timeouts. I have tried the following, but the error in the outer timeout (TimeoutError) may not be caught (Exception ignored). Would you please know how to implement nested timeout?

```
import signal
import multiprocessing
from timeout_timer import timeout, TimeoutInterrupt

def my_func():
   try:
       with timeout(TIMEOUT2, timer="signal", exception=TimeoutInterrupt):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_other_func)
            p.start()
            p.join()
   except TimeoutInterrupt:
        p.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    class TimeoutError(Exception):
        pass

    def handler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
    signal.alarm(TIMEOUT1)

    try:
        result = my_func()
    except TimeoutError as timeout_error:
        return result
```